# For geometric distribution how is $E[X]/(1-p)^2 = 1/p(1-p)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, fisher-information

Let X be geometrically distributed with parameter $0<p<1$. Therefore $E[X] = 1/p$.
Im trying to solve the fisher information but im stuck on how

$-E(1/p^2 + x(-1)/(1-p)^2)$ which = $1/p^2 + E[X]/(1-p)^2$ simplifies to become
$$1/p^2 +1/p(1-p)$$. which equals $$ 1/p(1-p)$$

How does it become $1/(p(1-p))$?
And why does the $1/p^2$ disappear?

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: That sure looks like a typo.

Comment: It was hand written by my lecturer and i've been confused for hours. So is it meant to be 1/p(1-p)^2 ?

Comment: I have no idea what it's supposed to be -- you might want to check with the person who wrote it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [two Distributions named Geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).   They appear to be using the "from-zero" supported sequence.

The distribution of *failures before the first success* in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $p$ has a Geometric Distribution with mean $(1-p)/p$.$$\begin{align}X&\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(p)\\[1ex] \mathsf P(X{=}k)&=(1-p)^k p~\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}\\[1ex] \mathsf E(X)&=\dfrac{1-p}p\end{align}$$

Then, *however*, we should have $$\begin{align}\dfrac 1{p^2}+\dfrac 1{p(1-p)} &= \dfrac{(1-p)+p}{p^2(1-p)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1}{p^2(1-p)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!